# Scrapy: store all external links and crawl all interal links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been working on a scrapy web scraper that crawls through all internal links from a start url and only collects external links with `scrapy`. However, my main problem is classifying the external links and internal links. For example, when I try to filter out external links with `link.startswith("http") or link.startswith("ftp") or link.startswith("www")`, if the website links its own website with an absolute path (`www.my-domain.com/about` instead of `/about`) then, it will classify it as the external link even if it's not. The following is my code:

```
import scrapy
from lab_relationship.items import Links

class WebSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "web"
    allowed_domains = ["my-domain.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'www.my-domain.com',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        """ finds all external links"""
        items = []
        for link in set(response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()):
            item = Links()
            if len(link) > 1:
                if link.startswith("/") or link.startswith("."):
                    # internal link
                    url = response.urljoin(link)
                    item['internal'] = url
                    #yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
                elif link.startswith("http") or link.startswith("ftp") or link.startswith("www"):
                    # external link
                    item['external'] = link
                else:
                    # misc. links: mailto, id (#)
                    item['misc'] = link
                items.append(item)
        return items
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [link extractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html).

When instantiating you have to pass allowed domain. You don't have to worry about specifying the required tags, as (according to docs) the parameter `tags` takes `('a', 'area')` by default.

On the example of Rust lang website, the code to print all the internal links from their domain would look like:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class RustSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "rust"
    allowed_domains = ["www.rust-lang.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.rust-lang.org/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        extractor = LinkExtractor(allow_domains='rust-lang.org')
        links = extractor.extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            print link.url
```

and the output would be a list of such links: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference.html (I can't post more), while excluding all the links like those to StackOverflow.

Please be sure to check out documentation page, as link extractor has many parameters you may need.

Comment: Hm.. are you suggesting making a set of internal links with LinkExtractor, and for all links, check if they match the internal links, and if no, they are external links?

Comment: Not exactly, by setting `deny_domains='domain'` you can extract links which are not in a given domain (external).

Answer (score -2):

The if can take multiple or statements, not just two.

Comment: But my array will include internal links as well. I only want external links

Comment: Yes, just noted that. Looking at your code, the "if link.startswith("/") or link.startswith("."):" line can have multiple "or" statements, otherwise maybe use a [switch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/switch) statement

Comment: I am already using multiple `or`s in my code, and I don't see how that will filter out absolute links from relative links

Comment: you know your internal domain, so if the link starts with the internal domain an additional if should pick up any internal domain?
ie: `link.startswith("http://www.my-domain.com/")`

Comment: The main problem is that using conditional statements classify www.my-domain.com under both external and internal links, when it should be internal. If it were, say, www.other-domain.com, then it should be classified under external.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I keep replying to the older comment. I thought about that, but the domain such as `blog.my-domain.com` should still qualify under internal link, no?

Comment: hence my suggestion of the switch statement, as once it matches you run your code and break. you could simply handle everything that doesn't match as a fallthrough

Comment: If we just try to match substring of the original domain, then even something like "facebook.com/my-domain.com" would fail

Comment: A regular expression would be better for this.